# Multiplos Ckeditor na mesma página

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Estou criando um sistema no qual o usuário pode colocar quantas textarea ela quiser, o sistema já está pronto. O código para fazer isso é esse:

```
function addPergunta(){
    pergunta++;
    var corpo = "<div id='pergunta-" + pergunta + "'><hr><h3>Pergunta " + pergunta + "</h3><textarea id='textEditor' class='textarea-pergunta' placeholder='Escreva a pergunta...'' name='pergunta-" + pergunta + "' required></textarea><div id='itens-" + pergunta + "'><div id='item-" + pergunta + "-1' style='display: inline'>1. <input type='text' class='item-pergunta' name='item-" + pergunta  + "-1' placeholder='Escreva a alternativa para essa pergunta' required></div></div><button type='button' class='add-item' onclick='addItem(" + pergunta + ")' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Adicionar ítem à questão' id='addItem-" + pergunta + "'><span class='fa fa-plus'></span></button><button type='button' class='add-item' onclick='removerItem(" + pergunta + ")' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Remover um ítem!' id='removerItem-1'><span class='fa fa-close'></span></button><input type='text' class='resposta' placeholder='Insira a resposta certa para essa questão' name='resposta-" + pergunta+ "' required></div>";
    var areaPerguntas = document.getElementById('perguntas');
    areaPerguntas.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', corpo);
    itens[pergunta] = 1;
    return;
}
```

O que importa é que eu crio essa textarea com javascript normal e tals. Mas eu queria colocar essa textarea como um editor de texto, eu já uso o CKeditor a um tempinho e gosto bastante dele, mas o que acontece é que eu não consigo carregar ele quando faço esse DOM, ele carrega uma única vez quando carrega a página. Se alguém tiver algum método de carregar ele toda vez que adiciona uma nova textarea.

**OBS.:** Não tem a id correspondente ao Ckeditor nesse código, é pq eu tirei enquanto não resolvia esse problema. E também já tentei carregar o CKeditor dentro dessa função, mas ele não carrega.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de dar um ID único a cada textarea. Por exemplo `'textEditor-pergunta-' + pergunta` para seguir a lógica que tens.

Feito isso podes fazer assim:

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('textEditor-pergunta-' + pergunta);
```

no final da tua função.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/f3054qmn/3/show/

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou, eu realmente estava deixando de identificar a textarea de forma correta.